# Not able to run shell script using cron

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I have a shell script `test.sh` in `/home/username`

The `test.sh` file contains the following lines -

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /home/username/bin

sh launch.sh  ParameterName

#launch.sh is in /home/username/bin directory
```

I have set up a crontab entry as follows -

```
* * * * * /home/username/test.sh
```

When I run `/home/username/test.sh` on terminal it is working properly. But it is not working from `cron`.

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using? do you have more processes running at crontab? are they running? have you try to add your path into the shell script?

Comment: Have you checked that everything your script needs is in the PATH cron provides? (e.g. by executing `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin /home/username/test.sh`).

Comment: If you run it without `sh` on the command line, and it fails when you run it with `sh` from the Cron job, that could be the problem.  Try without the `sh`. Is this actually a Bash script?

Answer (score 2):

Almost all problems with scripts properly running from the commandline, but not from `cron` come from the setting of the PATH variable. According to `man 5 crontab` for Vixie cron:

```
   On the Debian GNU/Linux system, cron supports the pam_env  module,  and
   loads  the  environment  specified  by  /etc/environment and /etc/secu‐
   rity/pam_env.conf.    It   also   reads   locale    information    from
   /etc/default/locale.   However,  the  PAM  settings do NOT override the
   settings described above nor any settings in the crontab  file  itself.
   Note  in particular that if you want a PATH other than "/usr/bin:/bin",
   you will need to set it in the crontab file.
```

Although the details might be different on other systems and/or other `cron` implementations **the PATH the script gets handed from cron is likely to be more restricted than the one in your shell**.

This means that anything your scripts (or the scripts/programs invoked from it) call that is in e.g. `/usr/local/bin` does not get found when running invoked from `cron`.

You can test this by calling your script the following way:

```
 PATH=/usr/bin:/bin /home/username/test.sh
```

You can solve this by extending your path in the crontab file:

```
 PATH = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

before the actual line of calling your script. Variables will not be substituted (so don't do `PATH = /usr/local/bin:$PATH`).

It also good practise to include an echo statement to some log file near the top of your script:

```
 TSTLOG=/var/tmp/myscript.log
 echo "invoking script" > "$TSTLOG"
 date >> "$TSTLOG"
 echo "$PATH" >> "$TSTLOG"
```

(overwriting by the `echo` on purpose here). So you can check that your program was called, and what kind of environment caused this.

You should also check your mail. On the system itself, if the system is not set up for forwarding email to your normal account. Many cron emails get unnoticed because there is no `MAILTO=your_email@your.provider` and the system just puts the messages where for the local account used for cron can read them.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

Option 1 - Have you `chmod +x test.sh`?

That way you can execute with `./test.sh` rather than `sh test.sh`.

Option 2 - If you don't want to chmod the file, change your crontab entry to

`* * * * * /usr/bin/sh /home/username/test.sh`

Additionally, if you choose the latter, you should verify the `sh` binary location with

`which sh`

Comment: None of these are necessary as the script runs from the commandline.

Comment: @Anthon The question is *how* they are being called. Sure they may be run manually from the commandline, but if they are being called differently from cron, that could be the problem. If you expect cron to run `./tests.sh` and only test it with `sh test.sh` you will have problems.

Comment: But the OP clearly states `/home/username/test.sh` is run from the commandline. Not that `sh` is run with some parameters. It is also way more likely that the OP has not restricted the PATH in his/her shell, the way that cron does.